# Create String from dataframe column and add delimiter

Tags: r

I have a column of data in a dataframe with ID values of type string.  I want to create a single string with all the values listed as such "'001000','001001'"

The string will be passed to an SQL query for an external database and used in the WHERE command.

The following code works:

```
vKey <- "'001004','001013'"
vA <- "SELECT A, B, C FROM filename WHERE ID in("
vB <- vKey
vC <- ")"
f <- dbSendQuery(ABCD, paste(vA, vB, vC))
```

I would like to create vKey from a local dataframe named dfKeys with the single column ID.  There will likely be several hundred unique ID's in the dfKeys dataframe, and the values will change between runs.

Comment: Do you mean something like `paste(DBI::dbQuoteString(con, mydat$mycolumn), collapse = ",")` (which produces your `vB`)?

Comment: r2evans - That! is exactly what I needed.  Installed the DBI package and the am ready to go.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Wait ... how did you not have the DBI package if you're using `dbSendQuery`?

Comment: (BTW: a somewhat equivalent if not idiomatic way would be to use `sQuote` instead, but that assumes that the DBMS you're accessing uses that as the string-literal thing.)